# Retrieve/send messages using Linkledin API V2

Tags: c#, linkedin-api

Is it possible to retrieve and send messages using linkedin API?

I have checked documentation on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/compliance/ and it says:

> The use of these APIs is restricted to developers approved by LinkedIn. Reach out to your LinkedIn Relationship Manager or Business Development contact as you will need to meet certain criteria and sign an API agreement with data restrictions in order to use this integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Linkedin APIs are focused towards organization usage and not for personal pet projects like what Google or Spotify APIs offer.

I wanted to fetch jobs based on criteria and than find keywords in JD and wanted to achieve the same using APIs but then realized they have restrictions.

So, you are only left with something like Selenium/Python unless your employer has an API contract with LinkedIn. LOL, then you would need to get approval for your "personal" use case.